# qgis TimeManager plugin won't install

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I'm running 2.14.11 and I'm getting the following error when trying to install TimeManager

Plugin installation failed:Failed to unzip the plugin package. Probably it's broken or missing from the repository. You may also want to make sure that you have write permission to the plugin directory:

Is this plugin no longer available?

Comment: Perhaps try [downloading the zipped file](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/timemanager/) and extract it to your `/.qgis2/python/plugins/` directory. Restart QGIS and see if that helps.